# How do I Post to .txt document before form submits

Tags: php, ajax, mailchimp

What I am trying to do is before I submit a form to Mailchimp with someones email I want to write that email to a .txt file. Mailchimp is using a "get" for the form and the "action" is run on mailchimp not the same page as form.  Here is my code for the form.

```
<form id="subscribe-form1" action="https://personaltrainer.us6.list-manage.com/subscribe/post-json?u=4aeb5b710adef51ab754ll02f&amp;id=76420114ff"
    method="get" class="form-inline">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" name="EMAIL">

        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-grn" type="submit button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style="visibility:collapse;" id="subscribe-result1"> </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="mce-group[6917]-6917-0" name="group[6917][1024]" value="1024" checked="checked" style="">
            I agree to recieve FREE newsletter from Personal Trainer Food </label>
        </div>  
     
 <?php //this only works if I change get->post and action ="" but then it does not submit to mail chimp.
//Get the email from POST
$email = $_REQUEST['EMAIL'];
$file = fopen("document.txt","a+");
fwrite($file,$email . "\n");


//redirect
?>    
      

</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try appending the values manually to the URL, then redirecting to it:

```
                                    ▼
  <form id="subscribe-form1" action="" method="get" class="form-inline">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" name="EMAIL">

        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-grn" type="submit button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style="visibility:collapse;" id="subscribe-result1"> </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="mce-group[6917]-6917-0" name="group[6917][1024]" value="1024" checked="checked" style="">
            I agree to recieve FREE newsletter from Personal Trainer Food </label>
        </div>  

 <?php //this only works if I change get->post and action ="" but then it does not submit to mail chimp.
//Get the email from GET ◄■■■
$email = $_REQUEST['EMAIL'];
$file = fopen("document.txt","a+");
fwrite($file,$email . "\n");                                          URL PARAMETERS START
fclose($file); // ◄■■■                                                           ▼
header("Location: https://personaltrainer.us6.list-manage.com/subscribe/post-json?u=4aeb5b710adef51ab754ll02f&id=76420114ff&EMAIL=$email"); // ◄■■■
exit; // ◄■■■
?>    

    </form>
```

Notice the original "chimp" URL contains an ampersand `$amp;` as HTML symbol. I think we can get rid of it and use the "natural" ampersand `&`.

There is a checkbox in your form, we can add it too:

```
fclose($file); // ◄■■■
if ( isset( $_GET["group[6917][1024]"] ) ) // IF CHECKBOX IS CHECKED...
     $chk = "&group[6917][1024]=1024";                                URL PARAMETERS START
else $chk = "";                                                                  ▼
header("Location: https://personaltrainer.us6.list-manage.com/subscribe/post-json?u=4aeb5b710adef51ab754ll02f&id=76420114ff&EMAIL=$email$chk"); // ◄■■■
exit; // ◄■■■
```

The variables `$email` and `$chk` are at the end of the URL. An example of the resulting URL would be:

> https://personaltrainer.us6.list-manage.com/subscribe/post-json?u=4aeb5b710adef51ab754ll02f&id=76420114ff&EMAIL=josmanaba@yahoo.com&group[6917][1024]=1024

**Edit :**

Added an `if` to the PHP code:

```
<?php
if ( isset( $_GET["EMAIL"] ) ) {
  $email = $_REQUEST['EMAIL'];
  if ( isset( $_GET["group"] ) )
       $chk = "&group[6917][1024]=1024";
  else $chk = "";
  header("Location: https://personaltrainer.us6.list-manage.com/subscribe/post-json?u=4aeb5b710adef51ab754ll02f&id=76420114ff&EMAIL=$email$chk");
  exit;
}
?>
```

**Edit #2 :**

```
<?php
if ( isset( $_GET["EMAIL"] ) ) {
  $email = $_REQUEST['EMAIL'];
  // SAVE EMAIL.
    $file = fopen("document.txt","a");
    fwrite($file,$email . "\n");
    fclose($file);
  if ( isset( $_GET["group"] ) )
       $chk = "&group[6917][1024]=1024";
  else $chk = "";
  header("Location: https://personaltrainer.us6.list-manage.com/subscribe/post-json?u=4aeb5b710adef51ab754ll02f&id=76420114ff&EMAIL=$email$chk");
  exit;
}
?>
```

**Edit #3**

Redirect with a form and auto-submit it with javascript:

```
<?php
if ( isset( $_GET["EMAIL"] ) ) {
  $email = $_REQUEST['EMAIL'];
  // SAVE EMAIL.
    $file = fopen("document.txt","a");
    fwrite($file,$email . "\n");
    fclose($file);
  if ( isset( $_GET["group"] ) )
       $chk = "&group[6917][1024]=1024";
  else $chk = "";
  echo "<form method='get'" .
       "      id='frm'" .
       "      target='_blank'" .
       "      action='https://personaltrainer.us6.list-manage.com/subscribe/post-json?u=4aeb5b710adef51ab754ll02f&id=76420114ff&EMAIL=$email$chk'>" .
       "</form>" .
       "<script type='text/javascript'>" .
       "document.getElementById('frm').submit();" .
       "</script>";
  exit;
}
?>
```

**Edit #4 :**

This is edit #2 but saving the URL in the textfile :

```
<?php
if ( isset( $_GET["EMAIL"] ) ) {
  $email = $_REQUEST['EMAIL'];
  if ( isset( $_GET["group"] ) )
       $chk = "&group[6917][1024]=1024";
  else $chk = "";
  $url = "https://personaltrainer.us6.list-manage.com/subscribe/post-json?u=4aeb5b710adef51ab754ll02f&id=76420114ff&EMAIL=$email$chk"
  // SAVE EMAIL.
    $file = fopen("document.txt","a");
    fwrite($file,$email . "\n");
    fwrite($file,$url . "\n");
    fclose($file);
  header("Location: $url");
  exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: I have upvoted, just because you have didactic chars on your answer

Comment: when i run the form with your code it stays on the same page.. it looks like it submits but the URL up top does not change..

Comment: It does not re-direct like that. it stays on the same page. it just submits email. stays on same page. Doesnt matter if it works or not. I receive an email every time it works. every time it does not work I do not get an email.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PTF_LOCAL/risk-free/includes/header.php on line 16

Notice: Undefined index: cid in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PTF_LOCAL/risk-free/includes/header.php on line 16

Comment: does not display anything

Comment: No it doesnt show a new URL like it doesnt change say i am on home/index.php it still says home/index.php after submit form.

Comment: No. even if I use the working version and submit to mail chimp it still does same thing. does not change.. stays on same page and I have a modal pop and say "form submited" still says home/index.php never does that change.

Comment: @davidthom42, oh, so you have something interfering with my form.

Comment: no. it just when button is clicked it pops up. but like i said. home/index.php stays the same. never ?24234fsdf341323&ff323r after it. its just stays the same working or not working. I knowit works when I recieve email from mail chimp saying its been submited. ALL I NEED. is to be able to write that email to txt file. I feel like this should be way easier.

Comment: @davidthom42, I edited again (#4) to save the URL in the file. Run the code again, open the file and take a look at the URL saved.

Comment: https://personaltrainerfood.us6.list-manage.com/subscribe/post-json?u=4aeb5b283adef51ab754dd02f&amp;id=76325114ff&EMAIL=bob@google.com&group[6917][1024]=1024

Comment: good it is what it is supposed to be. I dont know why it does not work though when we run it. in the form. like if I take that url and just go to it it will work.

Comment: @davidthom42, so, our URL works but something interferes with the redirection.

Comment: Yeah I guess so. Hey so I am out for the day but if you think of anything please post it.

Comment: @davidthom42, well, I just got another great idea. Let's separate the files : one file for the form and another file for the php script. Right now the action of the form is `""`, replace it with `"save_email.php"`, now create a new file with the name "save_email.php", **cut** the PHP code from the form file and **paste** it in the PHP file. Now run it.